# List of widget does not show on screen

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have this code that will get a list of reminders in DB and show it on the screen. It works fine with the reminder list. The problem is when the list is empty (there is no reminder), i want it to show some text like "There is no reminder". So i tried with Column, Text widget, i wrapped them in a list like below but nothing shown on screen.

If i remove the [], it is error **A value of type 'Card' can't be returned from the method 'buildReminderList' because it has a return type of 'List'**.

Does anyone know how to make a text like "There is no reminder" show in the case when "Upcoming" list is empty.

```
List<Widget> buildReminderList(List<Reminder> reminders) {
    debugPrint(reminders.length.toString());
    if (reminders != null)
      return reminders.map((Reminder reminder)
      => ListTile()).toList();
    else
      return [Card(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text("There is no reminder", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          )
      )];
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Result**

[image: output]

try this way

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Widget> buildReminderList() {
    return [
      Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text("There is no reminder",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ...buildReminderList().toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I try this, it runs fine but nothing show on screen, i even specify the color to be black, size: 20 but nothing is shown on screen. It works fine with the list but when the list is empty, nothing is shown this way.

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild. also replace `if (reminders != null)` with `if (reminders.length>0)`,

Comment: flutter clean works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `List<Widget>` with `Widget`:-

```
Widget buildReminderList(List<Reminder> reminders) {
    debugPrint(reminders.length.toString());
    if (reminders != null)
      return reminders.map((Reminder reminder)
      => ListTile()).toList();
    else
      return Text("There is no reminder", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold));
  }
```

Comment: If i replace it with widget and delete the .toList() function, it gets this error: "A value of type 'Iterable<ListTile>' can't be returned from the method 'buildReminderList' because it has a return type of 'Widget'."